# Select positive integers but not fractions

Tags: javascript

I am working through the fundamentals on Codewars and I am trying to add up all the whole numbers from 1 through a given number n.

I have to verify that n is a valid positive integer number. If it is not I must return false.

For example
f(n=100) // returns 5050

My solution so far works but only when n is not a fraction. How do I prevent the program from computing a fraction?

```
function f(n)
{
var total = 0, count = 1;
while (count <= n) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}


if (typeof n === 'number')
{
return total;
}
else{
return false;
}
};
```

Instead of (typeof n === 'number'), I need it to only compute a positive integer (as opposed to accepting a fraction, which is still a 'number').

How would you get the program to do this?

Please, I am working on the fundamentals so the simplest answer is most helpful.

Comment: Check for fraction: `yourNumber % 1 !== 0`

Comment: so it will be: `return typeof n == "number" && n>=0 && n%1==0?total:false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways to do that.

#### Check equalitity of rounded parameter

```
var isInt = function(i) { 
   return (typeof i === "number") && i === (~~ i) 
};
```

The `~~` operator is going to truncate every thing after the decimal point.

### Check the rest of dividing the number by one

```
function isInt(i) {
   return (typeof i === "number") && i % 1 === 0;
}
```

If the number is integer then after dividing it by 1 it should give you no rest.

### Convert number to string

```
var isInit = function(i) { 
   return (i + '').indexOf('.') === -1 
}
```

After adding empty string to number it will be converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

A fraction number will return you non-zero value when taken `mod` by 1. Using that your function can be modified as:

```
function f(n){
    if(typeof n != "number" || n <0 || n%1 !=0){
        return false;
    }
    // rest of your code
    var total = 0, count = 1;
    while (count <= n) {
        total += count;
        count += 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return comparison of the number as original and as integer:

```
function isPositiveInt(n) {return n >= 0 && n === (n|0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
  function f(n)
{
if(typeof n == "number" && Math.abs(n) ==n && Math.floor(n) == n)
return (1 + n)*(n/2);
else return 0;
}
```

[image]

Mathematical formula to get summary of 1..N numbers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

No hesitate to ask me any question

Good luck !